# HTML define what selection option is active

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I have a select box with the following (it has been shortened):

```
<select id="viewSelector" name="when" style="width:92%;">
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
</select>
```

If the user logs into the control panel and wants to change his country, he gets presented with this form. My problem is that everytime USA is the default and I can not change this depending on the users country. For example, the user lives in Australia. He wants to change his country to USA and goes to this page. I want the country that is displayed to be Australia. Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder - It is handy for trying things out bu more importantly to post questions to this message board without making the question too long. I agree that you should never use it in production.

Comment: @Farray - please do not use w3schools as reference. See http://w3fools.com

Comment: @Oded Sorry, it wasn't meant as a comprehensive answer - it was the very first google result and happened to have the answer to the question.  I personally don't like "LMGTFY" comments but wasn't sure how else to get that across.

Comment: @Farray - You could say that the question shows no research effort (or no effort at all, for that matter) and that the first google result has a perfectly good answer.

Comment: @Oded Good point.  My social skills are a little rusty this morning...

Comment: I wonder why my post was -1'd?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To preselect a value, just add the selected attribute to the desired option.

```
<select id="viewSelector" name="when" style="width:92%;">
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="Australia" selected="selected">Australia</option>
    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
</select>
```

This will preselect Australia for example.

Answer (score 5):

Use `selected` on the `<option>` tag that names the user's current country:

```
<option value="Australia" selected="selected">Australia</option>
```

So in PHP:

```
<select>
<?php
$countries = array('USA', 'Australia', 'Germany');
$current_country = 'Australia';

foreach($countries as $country) {
    if($country == $current_country) {
        echo '<option selected="selected">'.$country.'</option>';
    } else {
        echo '<option>'.$country.'</option>';
    }
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a `selected` attribute to the option you want to select, as described in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.6.1).

```
<select id="viewSelector" name="when"">
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="Australia" selected="selected">Australia</option>
    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
</select>
```

In your script, you need to emit this attribute for whatever default you want to display.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `selected` attribute of the `option` tag.

```
<select id="viewSelector" name="when" style="width:92%;">
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
    <option selected value="Germany">Germany</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The html looks like:

```
<option selected value="Australia">Australia</option>
```

In the php loop that builds this html, compare the current option name with the user's current country (retrieved from a database or where-ever). When the two match, add `selected`

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter:

```
foreach($paises as $key=>$value)
{
    if($key == "PE"){$activo = ' selected="selected" '; }else{$activo = "";}    
    echo "<option $activo value=\"$key\">$value</option>";
}
```